# D3 function crashes IE11

Tags: javascript, crash, internet-explorer-11, crash-reports

I'm using a D3 function to draw some text on screen

I narrowed down the problem to this function:

```
.append("text")
```

when I call that function many times, IE11 crashes with:

> Unhandled exception at 0x62E06A9C (mshtml.dll) in iexplore.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000028.

offending function is:

```
CSVGTextElement::GetBoundingRectImpl
```

here a snapshot of the output from the Windows Debugger. It shows what happen when the process iexplore.exe crashes

[image]

removing the calls to that `.append("text")` "solves" the problem, IE11 doesn't crash anymore. However, I need such function to draw some text on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a null pointer dereference bug in IE11. Check if you are using the latest IE version first, maybe it is already fixed. If not you should report it to MS and wait for them to fix it, you can do it here - https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback

Comment: I've the latest IE11. My colleague has the same version and it doesn't crash on his machine

Comment: Might be various reasons, are you using same Windows versions(builds)?Do this crash happens reliably on your machine? By reliably i mean everytime you run the code or just sometimes? If the latter maybe some low memory conditions / extensive use causes this to trigger. Hard to say.

Comment: IE11 crashes very consistently doing the same actions. Moved to D3 version 4 and it looks fine